# Ubuntu Component Showcase not working in 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk

I'm working through [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/apps/qml/tutorials/building-your-first-qml-app/) tutorial, but I'm unable to find the Component Showcase QML file using the provided path (/usr/lib/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/examples/ubuntu-ui-toolkit-gallery/ubuntu-ui-toolkit-gallery.qml).

Does anyone know if the file has been renamed/moved or if this feature no longer exists?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and QT Creator 3.5.1.

UPDATE: 
I was able to find the file using `find` ( /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/examples/ubuntu-ui-toolkit-gallery/ubuntu-ui-toolkit-gallery.qml), but when I try to open/run it per the instructions in the tutorial, (apparently) nothing happens.

One possible workaround is [this](https://github.com/bpierre/ubuntu-uitk-gallery-docker) Docker container which allows users to experiment with the gallery. I've built and run the container and it works as expected, but I'd really like to be able to run the gallery natively.